# NoModuleError after pip successful install (selenium)

Tags: selenium, pip

It have no issue install it, importing it, but if I try to run it its a no go

pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C29D0.jpg

I am on python 3.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your permissions:

`sudo pip install selenium`

For python3:

`sudo pip3 install selenium`

Comment: Yes that is what I did, trying to use it or import it results in the same error though